# Splitting and array using formtastic. Error: undefined method `map'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, psql, formtastic

I'm trying to turn my choices column from my Questionnaire table into separate strings as multiple choice.

Questionnaire Controller:

```
    class QuestionnairesController < ApplicationController

def index

    @questions = Questionnaire.find(params[:category_id])
    #params[:category_id]= <%=category.id%>
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    @videos = VideoClue.find(params[:category_id])
    ###This finds all the questions from the question table by their category_id. Whenever I select a category, it matches the question related to the category

    render :show
    ###render :show Renders Html page
end

def choose_answer
    # binding.pry
    @questions = Questionnaire.find(params[:id])
    #params[:id] = /:id  = /1


    render :choose_answer
    end





    end
```

Questionnaire Model:

```
class Questionnaire < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :categories

end
```

Chose_answer.html.erb

```
    <h1>Congrats You Hit The Choices Page!</h1>


    <%= semantic_form_for @questions.choices do |c| %>

    <%= c.inputs do %>

    <%= c.input :choices, :as => :check_boxes , :collection => 
   [@questions.choices].map(&:inspect).join(', ') %>

    <%end%>

    <%end%>
```

Questionnaire table seed:

```
    Questionnaire.create({question: "In that year did MTV (Music Television) 

    premiere and what was the first music video the channel aired?", choices:

    ["1982 Michael Jackson 'Bille Jean'", "1984 Madonna 'Like a virgn'", "1981

     The Buggles 'Video Killed The Radio Star'"], correct_answer:"1981 The 

    Buggles 'Video Killed The Radio Star' ", category_id:1})
```

@question.choices returns

```
    ["1982 Michael Jackson 'Bille Jean'", "1984   

    Madonna 'Like a virgn'", "1981 The Buggles 'Video Killed The Radio Star'"],
```

How do I separate the strings from the choices column array and use formtastic to turn the strings into a mutiple choice format?

Comment: What does `@questions.choices` return? Since I don't know how you are storing the data, I can't give an answer without seeing what it returns.

Comment: It's in Questionnaire.create table and it returns ["1982 Michael Jackson 'Bille Jean'", "1984 Madonna 'Like a virgn'", "1981

     The Buggles 'Video Killed The Radio Star'"]

Comment: I want to take all the strings from the choices array and turn them all into multiple choice

Answer (score 0):

`<%= c.input :choices, :as => :check_boxes , :collection => @questions.choices %>` should do what you want here, no need to modify it if it's already an array IIRC, unless I'm misunderstanding the situation.

Comment: I've tried that already and it only returns a checkbox with the array. I want to split the array. I want each of the element to have their own checkbox.

 IE

| check box | "1982 Michael Jackson 'Bille Jean'"

|check box | "1984 Madonna 'Like a virgn'"

 |checkbox | "1981 The Buggles 'Video Killed The Radio Star'"